# Swift5 how to pass function to a vector/ to a function

Tags: swift, swift5

Im trying to make a generator for my buttons/actions.
How could I do this? >

```
var buttonPairs = [
            [“Reset”,handleReset] // handleHeightReset - function in current self
]

for data in buttonPairs{
    mButtonPtrs[data[0] as! String] = UIButton()
    mButtonPtrs[data[0]!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(data[1]) , for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
}
```

I keep getting error :
`swift Argument of ‘#selector’ does not refer to an ‘@objc’ method, property, or initializer`

Comment: What is your deployment target? Is an iOS 14+ answer acceptable?

Comment: @jnpdx yup ios 14+, just noticed one answer will go over it see whats what o.o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this -

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

struct ButtonConfig {
    let title: String
    let action: Selector
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @objc func handleReset() {}
    
    var buttonConfigs: [ButtonConfig] = [
        .init(title: "Reset", action: #selector(handleReset))
    ]
    var buttonsCache: [String: UIButton] = [:]
    
    func prepareButtonsCache() {
        for config in buttonConfigs {
            let button = UIButton()
            button.addTarget(self, action: config.action, for: .touchUpInside)
            buttonsCache[config.title] = button
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: very very interesting, thank you! Will give it a go. But looks to me like it will work. Unless I get some "magical" issues ;- ) thank you!